# How to execute an Array of CompletableFuture and compose their results

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I am investigating Java 8 `CompletableFutures` and read (and seen) that I should employ `thenCompose` instead of `thenApply`.

I have converted my code to use `thenCompose` but I have a feeling in an incorrect manner.

Here is my controlling code...

```
final CompletableFuture<List<String>> extractor = get(htmlPageSource);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final CompletableFuture<List<Documentable>>[] completableFutures =
   new CompletableFuture[ENDPOINT.EXTRACTABLES.size()];
int index = 0;
for( ENDPOINT endpoint : ENDPOINT.EXTRACTABLES ) {
   final CompletableFuture<List<Documentable>> metaData =
      extractor.thenComposeAsync(
         s -> endpoint.contactEndpoit(s), executorService );
   completableFutures[index++] = metaData.exceptionally(x -> failedList(x));
}
CompletableFuture
   .allOf( completableFutures )
   .thenComposeAsync( dummy -> combineDocuments( completableFutures ))
   .thenAccept   ( x -> finish( x ))
   .exceptionally( x -> failed( x ));

private List<Documentable> failedList(final Throwable x) {
   LOGGER.error("failedList", x);
   final List<Documentable> metaData = new ArrayList<>();
   return metaData;
}

private Void failed(final Throwable x) {
   LOGGER.error("failed", x);
   return null;
}
```

Which I believe is acceptable

However the code that makes me uneasy is this:-

```
WWW_SITE_ONE("https://example.site.one/") {
   @Override
   public <T extends Documentable> CompletionStage<List<T>> contactEndpoit( final List<String> elements) {
      LOGGER.info("WWW_SITE_ONE " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      final List<T> SITE_ONEs = new ArrayList<>();
      for (final String element : elements) {
         try {
            final String json = Jsoup.connect(ENDPOINT.WWW_SITE_ONE.getBaseUrl() + element).ignoreContentType(true).ignoreHttpErrors(true).maxBodySize(0).timeout(60000).execute().body();
            if (json.contains("errors")) {
               continue;
            }
            final T SITE_ONE = OBJECT_READER_SITE_ONE.readValue(json);
            SITE_ONEs.add(SITE_ONE);
         }
         catch( final Throwable e ) {
            LOGGER.error("WWW_SITE_ONE failed", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
      }
      return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> SITE_ONEs);  
   }
},
WWW_SITE_TWO("https://example.site.two/") {
   @Override
   public <T extends Documentable> CompletionStage<List<T>> contactEndpoit(final List<String> elements) {
      LOGGER.info("WWW_SITE_TWO " + Thread.currentThread().getName());      
      final List<T> SITE_TWOs = new ArrayList<>();
      for (final String element : elements) {
         try {
            final String json = Jsoup.connect(ENDPOINT.WWW_SITE_TWO.getBaseUrl() + element).ignoreContentType(true).ignoreHttpErrors(true).maxBodySize(0).timeout(60000).execute().body();
            if (json.equals("Resource not found.")) {
               continue;
            }
            final T SITE_TWO = OBJECT_READER_SITE_TWO.readValue(json);
            SITE_TWOs.add(SITE_TWO);
         }
         catch (final Throwable e) {
            LOGGER.error("WWW_SITE_TWO failed", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
      }
      return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> SITE_TWOs);  
   }
},
WWW_SITE_THREE("https://example.site.three/") {
   @Override
   public <T extends Documentable> CompletionStage<List<T>> contactEndpoit(final List<String> elements) {
      LOGGER.info("WWW_SITE_THREE " + Thread.currentThread().getName());        
      final List<T> SITE_THREEs = new ArrayList<>();
      for (final String element : elements) {
         try {
            final String SITE_THREEJsonString = Jsoup
               .connect( ENDPOINT.WWW_SITE_THREE.getBaseUrl() + element)
               .ignoreContentType(true)
               .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
               .maxBodySize(0)
               .timeout(60000)
               .execute()
               .body();
            final SITE_THREE SITE_THREE_Json = OBJECT_READER_SITE_THREE.readValue(SITE_THREEJsonString);
            final T SITE_THREE = (T) SITE_THREE_Json;
            if (SITE_THREE_Json.getHitCount() > 0) {
               SITE_THREEs.add(SITE_THREE);
            }
         }
         catch (final Throwable e) {
            LOGGER.error("WWW_SITE_THREE failed", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
      }
      return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> SITE_THREEs);  
   }
};
```

Its where I am `return`ing `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> SITE_THREEs);`

Is this the correct approach?

Or does this start another asynchronous thread to simply return my List<>?

Comment: `thenCompose` and `thenApply` have different purposes but you should use one or the other depending on your use case. Here there does not seem to be much added value in returning a `CompletionStage` from your `contactEndpoit()` (sic) methods. You could simply return the result and chain everything with `thenApplyAsync()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name suggests, `supplyAsync` will perform an asynchronous operation, executing the `Supplier`’s `get()` method, hence the body of the lambda expression, in a background thread, regardless of how trivial it is. Since the implementation of `supplyAsync` has no way to check how trivial the code encapsulated by the `Supplier` is, it has to work this way.

Instead of `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> SITE_THREEs)`, you should use [`CompletableFuture.completedFuture(SITE_THREEs)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completedFuture-U-) which returns a future that has already been completed with the result, hence, not requiring additional actions.

If the method only returns completed stages or throws an exception, you may also change it to return the result value instead of a `CompletionStage` and use `thenApply` instead of `thenCompose`, simplifying your code—unless you want to keep the option of introducing asynchronous operations in a future version of that method.