# Getting an HTML file after its javascript init methods loads in Java

Tags: javascript, java, jsoup, http-get

I have a Java code in which I want to load an HTML file and parse it. I am using **jsoup** library and everything is OK.

The problem is when I GET the HTML resource, it takes some time with the page being loaded and completed, possibly some JavaScript code is running and fetching data from DB to put into HTML resource.

But when getting the resource with Java, It does not wait for it to be completed and returns an HTML file with empty fields.

I have tried the classic **jsoup** way:

```
Connection conn = Jsoup.connect("http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=43362635835198978");
Document doc = conn.get(); 
String title = doc.title();
System.out.println(title);
```

And **WebClient** package:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60);
client.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(5000);
HtmlPage page = client.getPage("http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=43362635835198978");
String pageTxt = page.asText();
System.out.println(pageTxt);
```

But neither worked.

How can I make my program wait until everything is complete?

Answer (score 1):

To return a html resource once it has loaded you need to retrieve the data asynchronously. To achieve this I believe you want to use a Java Future. Try looking into the CompletetableFuture class [Java Futures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

You could also have a look at this Question and Answer [How to execute an array of CompletetableFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299556/how-to-execute-an-array-of-completablefuture-and-compose-their-results)

As a side note to do so in JavaScript this can be done using a Callback or Promise, the pros and cons of which are outlined here: [Javascript Promises](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)